# Login using POST with RestKit returns 404 error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, post, restkit

I'm totally new to RestKit and I'm trying to use a POST request to login to my system. I'm using RestKit version 0.20.3 and this is how I did:

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    NSString *email = [self.emailTextField text];
    NSString *password = [self.passwordTextField text];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://myhost.com/api.php"];
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
    NSDictionary *tmp = @{@"rquest":@"user",
                          @"tag":@"login",
                          @"email":email,
                          @"password":password};
    [manager postObject:tmp path:@"" parameters:nil
                success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                    NSDictionary *result = [mappingResult dictionary];
                    if([[result objectForKey:@"success"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]){
                        NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                        [def setBool:YES forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];
                        // set user details...
                        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                    }
                }
                failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                    message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                    NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
                }];
}
```

As you can see, since I don't really need to map the response into an object, I tried to access the response data with `NSDictionary`. I'm not sure if this is the problem, but when I try to run the above code, I get the error:

```
013-10-06 11:24:51.897 Eateries[1182:454b] E restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:304 Failed to parse response data: Loaded an unprocessable response (404) with content type 'application/json'
2013-10-06 11:24:51.902 Eateries[1182:1003] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:243 POST 'http://myhost.com/api.php' (404 Not Found / 0 objects) [request=0.1479s mapping=0.0000s total=0.1648s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1017 "Loaded an unprocessable response (404) with content type 'application/json'" UserInfo=0x8ee81e0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myhost.com/api.php, NSUnderlyingError=0x8ef4ea0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable response (404) with content type 'application/json'}
2013-10-06 11:24:51.978 Eateries[1182:a0b] Hit error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1017 "Loaded an unprocessable response (404) with content type 'application/json'" UserInfo=0x8ee81e0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myhost.com/api.php, NSUnderlyingError=0x8ef4ea0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable response (404) with content type 'application/json'}
```

I'm really confused because I don't really know what I did wrong here. If you have any suggestion, please kindly let me know. Thank you.

P.s: I changed the name of my host just for my personal purpose, but my server really responses ok with the request when I try to test it from other platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong API.

`postObject:...` is meant for posting an object to be mapped, meaning that the `object` parameter - if not `nil` - will be used as target to map the response.

If you don't want to map the response, just use the underlying `AFHTTPClient` to perform a plain POST request.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient postPath:@"" parameters:tmp success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // ...
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly where the problem lies.